# Usar "SUM" em access + vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, microsoft-access

Estou com um pequeno problema na consulta ao Access , onde tenho o seguinte codigo :

```
 Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim Da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim Dt As New DataTable
    Dim dtinicio As String
    Dim dtfim As String
    Dim NO As String
    dtinicio = txtDt1.Text
    dtfim = txtDt2.Text()
    NO = TextBox1.Text
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Firebird.mdb"
    cn.Open()
    txtDt1.Text = CDate(txtDt1.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    txtDt2.Text = CDate(txtDt2.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Try
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtInicio", dtinicio)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtFim", dtfim)
            .CommandText = "SELECT dt , SUM(UNI) AS UNI FROM RELATORI WHERE dt between @dtInicio and @dtFim ORDER BY dt  ORDER BY dt"
             .Connection = cn
        End With
        With Da
            .SelectCommand = cmd
            Dt = New DataTable
            .Fill(Dt)
            RELATORIDataGridView.DataSource = Dt
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

o que preciso , seria incluir na linha :

```
.CommandText = "SELECT dt , SUM(UNI) AS UNI FROM RELATORI WHERE dt between @dtInicio and @dtFim ORDER BY dt  ORDER BY dt"
```

mais alguns campos com o SUM, no caso mais 3 .
não consegui achar uma maneira de inserir os outros campos que no caso seria "VENDA" , "GRUPO"  , "CUPOM" .
Alguem teria um exemplo de como faço isso ?

Comment: Você quer somar as quantidades de vendas, grupos e cupons ou quer que elas apareçam no agrupamento?

Comment: tenho o grupo de bolos cafés e refrigerantes , quero agrupas os bolos vendidos dentro do grupo de bolo e etc. somar as unidades que vendi, e o valor que tive ao total com cada grupo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo:

```
.CommandText = @"SELECT dt, GRUPO, SUM(UNI) AS UNI, SUM(VENDA) as Vendas, SUM(CUPOM) as Cupons
         FROM RELATORI 
         WHERE dt between @dtInicio and @dtFim 
         GROUP BY dt, Grupo
         ORDER BY dt"
```

Comment: como sempre , certo . obrigado.